# Calculating a row percentage for a specific value in R

Tags: r, percentage

I've been trying to find a way to calculate the proportion of 1 count in each row in R.
For example, in following data. 15090 is have one 1 in 5 votes, so his proportion is 0.2
In the next row, he has four 1s out of 5 votes, so the proportion is 0.8.
I need to make NA to be dismissed in the calculation, i.e. should not be included in the denominator.

```
ICPSR         Vote.335 Vote.354 Vote.971 Vote.972 Vote.973 Vote.155 Vote.295 
15090         0        0        0        1        0        NA       NA
29300         1        1        1        0        1        NA       NA
```

What code should in R, to calculate each row's proportion of 1?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you share some of the code you've used and why it didn't work?  As it stands now, it sounds like you're asking us to write your code for you.

Answer (score 2):

`prop.table()` and `addmargins()` do that.

Answer (score 1):

Here a vectorized solution using `rowSums`:

```
dat <- dat[,-1]
rowSums(dat==1,na.rm=TRUE)/rowSums(!is.na(dat))
 [1] 0.2 0.8
```

where `dat`:

```
dput(dat)

structure(list(ICPSR = c(15090L, 29300L), Vote.335 = 0:1, Vote.354 = 0:1, 
    Vote.971 = 0:1, Vote.972 = c(1L, 0L), Vote.973 = 0:1, Vote.155 = c(NA, 
    NA), Vote.295 = c(NA, NA)), .Names = c("ICPSR", "Vote.335", 
"Vote.354", "Vote.971", "Vote.972", "Vote.973", "Vote.155", "Vote.295"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the columns contain `0`s and `1`s only, you can use

```
rowMeans(dat[-1], na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 0.2 0.8
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.